# angular JS dynamic tooltip creation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tooltip, angular-bootstrap

**EDIT**:
It seems like the Error or wrong handling is because the scope does not gets updated when the email field is not valid... is there a way to chang that?

this is my first question on stackoverflow so i hope i will do it right.

I am pretty new to angular js and i am creating some basics at the moment. 
in my demo app i created a normal form in a bootstrap style and i was planing to create a directive to show the errors in a bootstrap way. so far so good. that was working and my next step was to create a angular js bootstrap tooltip directive when the form is not valid. the thing is, that i wanna do this dynamic.

i post some code to explain it better:

```
<b>HTML:</b>

     <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl as vm">
            <form id="login" name="vm.loginForm" class="form-signin" ng-submit="vm.login()" novalidate>

                <div show-errors>
                    <input type="email" name="username" ng-model="vm.credentials.username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div show-errors>
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="vm.credentials.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                 </div>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" type="submit">
                    Login
                    <span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>
                </button>
            </form>
</div>

<b>showError Directive:</b>

    (function () {

    angular.module('testapp.Validate', []).directive('showErrors', validationDirective);

    /**
     * @name validate directive
     */
    function validationDirective($compile) {
        return {
            require: '^form',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
                var inputNgEl = angular.element(el[0].querySelector("[name]"));
                var inputName = inputNgEl.attr('name');

                inputNgEl.bind('blur', function () {
                    toogle(inputNgEl, el, formCtrl[inputName]);
                });

                scope.$on('show-errors-check', function () {
                    toogle(inputNgEl, el, formCtrl[inputName]);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function toogle(inputNgEl, fromGroup, inputField) {

        fromGroup.toggleClass('has-feedback has-error', inputField.$invalid);
        if (inputField.$invalid && !fromGroup[0].querySelector(".glyphicon-remove")) {
            inputNgEl.after('<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-remove"></span>');
        } else if (!inputField.$invalid) {
            if (fromGroup[0].querySelector(".glyphicon-remove") != null) {
                fromGroup[0].querySelector(".glyphicon-remove").remove();
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

That is working so far . it just adds a has-feedback,has-error class to the parent div and a span with an error-icon after the input.

but back to my plan, now I also want to create a dynamic tooltip for the input. so I planed to add something like that in the "toogle" function

```
inputNgEl.attr('uib-tooltip',"aaaa");
        inputNgEl.attr('tooltip-placement',"right");
        inputNgEl.attr('tooltip-trigger',"mouseenter");
        inputNgEl.attr('tooltip-class',"testTool");
```

But that is not working because the input field got already compiled before.
so I asked google about it and there I found some solutions with $compile

```
$compile(inputNgEl)(scope);
```

But when I am using it, and I type in a valid email address the field gets reset. aaa@aaa (still working) but after I add the aaa@aaa. (the field gets reseted - I guess compiled again). the tooltip would work btw.

Can anybody help me with that or is there a better solution to create a dynamic angular bootstrap tooltip?

Comment: Have you tried angular bootstrap ? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

Comment: i am using this component but i am adding the "tooltip" attributes later because its dynamic of the form validation. and now i dont know how to connect these parts or to recompile it right

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add a $watch on the input element, and see if it changes, add a tooltip in the input element and compile it

Comment: i already found the mistake. the scope of the ngmodel (input) gets not updated when its not valid. so the data binding is just working if the ngModel is valid. is there a way to also update it when its invalid?